# java how do I put Preferences in a specific folder?

Tags: java, preferences

prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("VAR_PREFS"+userName);

Appears to put prefs in my registry. Is there a way I could specify a file in a specific folder instead?

like:

prefs = Preferences.folder("/usr/mypath/VAR_PREFS"+userName);

Comment: Preferences work based on the implementation, e.g., on Windows it goes in the registry.

Comment: Is there an alternative that uses normal files?

Comment: Use something like Apache Commons Configuration, or just use normal properties.